# Visual Studio 2017 Named Argument Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio 2017, is there a way to get syntax highlighting for named arguments without using Resharper?

```
public void TestThis(string name, string title)
{
    //Do something
}

public void TestThat()
{
    var name = string.Empty;
    var title = string.Empty;

    TestThis(
      name: name,  //highlight "name:"
      title: title); //highlight "title:"
}
```

Comment: And without writing your own add-on to do it?

Comment: Is `string.empty` a typo for `string.Empty`?